# files related to process core dump creation in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, coredump

just need to look for process core dump creation in linux kernel. Can anybody please point me out what files to see for x86. Specifically, i'll be looking for if the procedure can be tweaked to pass on certain information via proc file system from the user process. The result will be a core dump file which may contain certain additional info.

Thanks,
Kapil upadhayay

Answer (score 0):

Core dump generation is in function [do_coredump](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.0.4/+code=do_coredump). For setting things via proc filesystem, see how other parameters to that function like `core_pattern` (search for variable of that name) are implemented.